# Mapping Optimising

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below which works, but it takes ages to complete (30K+records).  Any suggestions on how it could be sped up?

```
Sub PelsisMapping()
Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim foundCell As Range

'Set sheets
'Sheet to Amend
Set sh1 = Sheets("STOCK PELSIS 1")
'Sheet that has mapping data
Set sh2 = Sheets("Mapping")

'set the start row for Sheet1
startRow = 4

'loop until column H of Sheet1 is blank
Do While sh1.Range("H" & startRow) <> ""

  'search id of column A of sheet2 from column H of Sheet2
  Set foundCell = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(sh1.Range("H" & startRow), LookIn:=xlValues)

  'If match id is found, add text in column U of Sheet1. overwriting what is already there
  If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    sh1.Range("U" & startRow) = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End If

  'increase row
  startRow = startRow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `application.screenupdating = false` at the beginning and `=true` at the end?

Comment: Adding to @CallumDA suggestion, if your sheets have formulas, `Application.Calculation = xlManual` at the start and  
`Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic`at the end

Comment: @CallumDA - Worked a Treat!!

Comment: @Moacir - Worked a Treat!!